# Bad handler error when running AWS Lambda with console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.8, tagging

I try to do Amazon S3 Bucket resource tagging with AWS Lambda. I need Lambda function to take tags from users and apply them to newly uploaded objects in an Amazon S3 Bucket.

I think get_user_tags in handler is the faulty part

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

#Get uncompressed CloudWatch Event data for parsing API calls
def get_unc_cw_event_data(event):
    cw_data_dict = dict()
    cw_data_dict = event['detail']
    return cw_data_dict

#Get resource tags assigned to a specified IAM role 
#Returns a list of key:string,value:string resource tag dictionaries
def get_user_tags(user_name):
    try:
        client = boto3.client('iam')
        response = dict()
        response = client.list_user_tags(
            UserName=user_name
        )
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        print("Boto3 API returned error: ", error)
        print("No Tags Applied To: ", resource_id)
        no_tags = list()
        return no_tags
    return response['Tags']

#Get resource tags stored in AWS SSM Parameter Store 
#Returns a list of key:string,value:string resource tag dictionaries
def get_ssm_parameter_tags(role_name, user_name):
    tag_list = list()
    try:
        path_string = "/auto-tag/" + role_name + "/" + user_name + "/tag"
        ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
        get_parameter_response = ssm_client.get_parameters_by_path(
        Path=path_string,
        Recursive=True,
        WithDecryption=True
        )
        for parameter in get_parameter_response['Parameters']:
            tag_dictionary = dict()
            path_components = parameter['Name'].split("/")
            tag_key = path_components[-1]
            tag_dictionary['Key'] = tag_key
            tag_dictionary['Value'] = parameter['Value']
            tag_list.append(tag_dictionary)
        return tag_list

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        print("Boto3 API returned error: ", error)
        tag_list.clear()
        return tag_list

#Apply tags to resource
def set_resource_tags(resource_id, resource_tags):
    # Is this an EC2 resource?
    if re.search("^i-", resource_id):
        try:
            client = boto3.client('ec2')
            response = client.create_tags(
                Resources=[
                    resource_id
                ],
                Tags=resource_tags
            )
            response = client.describe_volumes(
                Filters=[
                    {
                        'Name': 'attachment.instance-id',
                        'Values': [
                            resource_id
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            )
            try:
                for volume in response['Volumes']:
                    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
                    ec2_vol = ec2.Volume(volume['VolumeId'])
                    vol_tags = ec2_vol.create_tags(
                    Tags=resource_tags
                    )
            except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
                print("Boto3 API returned error: ", error)
                print("No Tags Applied To: ", response['Volumes'])
                return False
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
            print("Boto3 API returned error: ", error)
            print("No Tags Applied To: ", resource_id)
            return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

data_dict = get_unc_cw_event_data(event)
#data_dict = get_cw_event_data(event)
user_id_arn = data_dict['userIdentity']['arn']
user_id_components = user_id_arn.split("/")
user_id = user_id_components[-1]
#role_arn = data_dict['userIdentity']['sessionContext']['sessionIssuer']['arn']
role_arn = data_dict['userIdentity']['arn']
role_components = role_arn.split("/")
role_name = role_components[-1]
resource_date = data_dict['eventTime']

resource_role_tags = list()
resource_role_tags = get_role_tags(role_name)

resource_parameter_tags = list()
resource_parameter_tags = get_ssm_parameter_tags(role_name, user_id)

resource_tags = list()
resource_tags = resource_role_tags + resource_parameter_tags

created_by = dict()
created_by['Key'] = 'Created by'
created_by['Value'] = user_id
resource_tags.append(created_by)

roleName = dict()
roleName['Key'] = 'Role Name'
roleName['Value'] = role_name
resource_tags.append(roleName)

date_created = dict()
date_created['Key'] = 'Date created'
date_created['Value'] = resource_date
resource_tags.append(date_created)

if 'instancesSet' in data_dict['responseElements']:
    for item in data_dict['responseElements']['instancesSet']['items']:
        resource_id = item['instanceId']
        if set_resource_tags(resource_id, resource_tags):    
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'Resource ID': resource_id,
                'body': json.dumps(resource_tags)
            }
        else:
            return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'No tags applied to Resource ID': resource_id,
                'Lambda function name': context.function_name,
                'Lambda function version': context.function_version
            }
else:
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'No resources to tag': event['id']
    }
```

And the resulting error is this:

> Response {   "errorMessage": "Bad handler
> 'resource-auto-tagger-main/source/resource-auto-tagger': not enough
> values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)",   "errorType":
> "Runtime.MalformedHandlerName",   "stackTrace": []

I run my first AWS Lambda, so will be happy about any help.

Comment: I would start by reading the basic documentation on what a AWS Lambda Python handler function should look like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Comment: this is part of handler, i will update right now

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use an AWS Lambda function to tag objects that are located in an Amazon S3 bucket. There is a development article that shows this use case. It's implemented in Java; however, it will point you in the right direction and you can port to your programming language.

[Creating an Amazon Web Services Lambda function that tags digital assets located in Amazon S3 buckets](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_tag_assets)

In this example, the Lambda function reads all objects in a given Amazon S3 bucket. For each object in the bucket, it passes the image to the Amazon Rekognition service to generate a series of labels. Each label is used to create a tag that is applied to the image. After you execute the Lambda function, it automatically creates tags based on all images in a given Amazon S3 bucket and applies them to the images.